# Email was sent but not in the inbox. It was in the spam. Why is this happening?

Tags: java, email, server, smtp

I am making a program that will send an email. It is successfully sent but whenever I check my email, It was stored in spam instead of inbox. Any reason why is this happening?

```
public static void send() {
        String to = "rchiluano@partnersolutions.com.ph";
        String from = "hryanmark@gmail.com";
        String host = "localhost";
        String msgbody ="Please Click the Link:\n";
        String linktest = "http://localhost:50000/first_ecom/VerifiedSuccessfuly.risc?ccstyle=defaultrisc";

        Properties properties = System.getProperties();
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);


        try{
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(to));
            message.setSubject("Verify your Account.");
            message.setText(msgbody+linktest);


            Transport.send(message);
            System.out.println("Sent");

        }catch (MessagingException mex) {mex.printStackTrace();}

    }
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13953303/mail-repeatedly-sent-by-javamail-ends-up-in-spam-folder

Comment: This has nothing to do with your Java program.  The e-mail program on the receiving end makes the decision whether to treat mail as spam.  The owner of that program would probably be `partnersolutions.com.ph`, or an e-mail service that `partnersolutions.com.ph` uses to process incoming e-mail.  Without knowing what the policies are, there's no way to help you.  If this is a real problem, you'll need to contact them.  Since it's looks like you're writing a test program for practice, you'll probably just have to live with it.

Comment: emails with subject as "Verify Your Account" and message body starting with "Please Click The Link" are very commonly considered as spam. There is nothing that you are doing wrong. I would recommend copy paste the subject and body of a regular email you got from a friend/colleague and try this again and see if it now goes to spam (I would recommend changing the "From" email-id too as the spam engine on the recipient side would have marked the email-id "hryanmark@gmail.com" as a Spam generating email id.

Comment: I appreciate your answers guys, thank you very much. Now I completely understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it is a kind of spam. Your E-mail `from` field says that it was sent from `hryanmark@gmail.com`, But you are not using Gmail and same address to send this E-mail. It's like you are using fake identity to send the e-mail. So your incoming mail server which is `partnersolutions.com.ph` think it is a spam mail.

Comment: Thank you very much. This solve my problem. I change my smtp to gmail and it worked fine now.

Answer (score 0):

your ip is not safe？

please change another service .